# What difference between Android Mobile OS and Android Wear OS?

Tags: android, git, operating-system, wear-os

I was downloaded Android wear OS(lollipop) and compared to Android Mobile OS(lollipop). (Two full source was downloaded from android git repositories)

Result of the comparisons, I did not find the difference.(roughly 98%)

If so, what  difference between Android Mobile OS and Android Wear OS?

Answer (score 0):

Wear OS is not open source. The code which you download from aosp may be tagged with xxx-wear, but some code of wear os is not published to android source.

Answer (score 0):

Wear Os has pre-made example builds for a simple clockface and a simple clock app that work with the companion Wear OS app on your Android device. When you build and run your clockface it will pop up in the Wear OS app , so you can use that app to then put it in your Wear OS clockface library. Your API should be 28 - 31 if you are publishing for Wear Os apps or clockfaces to Google Play Store.